# Initialize list with same bool value

Tags: python, list, initialization, boolean

Is it possible without loops initialize all list values to some bool? For example I want to have a list of N elements all False.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can do it like this: -

```
>>> [False] * 10
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

**NOTE: -**
Note that, you should never do this with a `list` of `mutable types` with same value, else you will see surprising behaviour like the one in below example: -

```
>>> my_list = [[10]] * 3
>>> my_list
[[10], [10], [10]]
>>> my_list[0][0] = 5
>>> my_list
[[5], [5], [5]]
```

As you can see, changes you made in one inner list, is reflected in all of them.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct idiom for this problem.  However, it is absolutely the incorrect idiom to use when you're dealing with a mutable type:  `[[]]*10` has some surprising consequences for new comers :).

Comment: See [this link](https://bugs.python.org/issue27135) why you shouldn't create a list of mutable types using multiplication.

Answer (score 19):

```
    my_list = [False for i in range(n)]
```

This will allow you to change individual elements since it builds each element independently.

Although, this technically *is* a loop.

Answer (score 5):

When space matters, [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) is a better choice. It's roughly five times more space efficient than the list of boolean solution.

This creates an array of `N` values, initialized to zero:

```
B = bytearray(N)
```