# Initializing a large list of booleans in Python

Tags: python, list, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initialize list with same bool value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382774/initialize-list-with-same-bool-value)

I'm attempting to make a prime number generator in python 2.7 and plan to use an array (or list) of booleans which will indicate whether a given number is prime.

Let's say I wanted to initialize a list of 5000 booleans, how would I do so without having to manually type `[True, True, ...]`

Comment: See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382804/1679863

Comment: For such a big list, it is probably worth using a Numpy array - `np.repeat([True], 5000)` uses three orders of magnitude less memory than `[True] * 5000`.

Comment: For large numerical problems, bytearray is the better choice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42445940/74291

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try this:

```
[True] * 5000
```

Lists can be multiplied in Python (as can strings):

```
>>> [True] * 3
[True, True, True]
>>> "abc" * 3
'abcabcabc'
```

Comment: Just as a side note: This works well for lists of primitive types, such as numbers and booleans, but not for lists of objects (or lists of lists, lists or dicts, etc.), as in this case the list will contain 5000 times _the same_ instance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to make a prime number generator in python 2.7 and plan to use an array (or list) of booleans which will indicate whether a given number is prime.

This sounds really wasteful. A better approach would be to have a `set()` with only the numbers you need:

```
>>> primes = {2, 3, 5, 7}
>>> 4 in primes
False
>>> 5 in primes
True
```

Comment: So you suggest him to manually type {2, 3, 5, 7 ...} instead of [True, True, True ...]. Interesting approach.

Comment: Because there was a downvote I have to say I heartfully agree! The distance between 2 primes becomes increasingly larger, so the bigger you go the more wasteful `false` elements you have.

Comment: +1 this would of course be a better approach.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky No I'm giving an example use for a `set()` (hint: it's a function!). If someone says that they're writing a generator I assume they know it won't come down to calculating them on paper and typing into the program.

Comment: I'm not saying using a set is not a better option, I just pointed out he didn't answer the question.

Comment: @lqc, the OP probably wants to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, which is based on that list initialization. You actually suggest him to implement a different algorithm.