# Ids of Mutable objects in a Python List

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have been using the `[Value] * Count` notation in Python for initializing a list. For eg., `[False] * 3` results in creation of list `[False, False False]`. I tried using the same notation for initializing a list of lists.

```
>>>a = [[0] * 2] * 3
>>>print a
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>>a[0][1] = 23
>>>print a
[[0, 23], [0, 23], [0, 23]]
>>>id(a[0])
139978350226680
>>>id(a[1])
139978350226680
>>>id(a[2])
139978350226680
```

As we can see, the elements of a refer to a single list thrice instead of referring to three different lists. 
1. Why does this happen?
2. What is the correct way to initialize a list of lists?

The same behavior has been pointed out in an answer previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382804/4716199

Comment: The "correct" way is to use a for-loop or list comprehension.

Comment: If you did `b = [0] * 2; a = [b] * 3` would you be surprised that `a` contains 3 references to `b`?

Comment: @PM2Ring That makes sense. I did not realise that * does not create new copies, it just copies the reference. Thanks :)

Comment: You may also find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM2Ring The article was useful. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the behavior of the `*` operator on a list: it does **not make copies**, but **copies the reference**. That makes sense since it is in general *not even defined* how to make copies, so Python can only copy the reference since it is the only thing every object has.

In case you want to construct new lists, you can use list comprehension:

```
a = [[0] * 2 for _ in range(3)]
```

In general it is **not good practice** to use `*` given the list **contains mutable objects**.

For immutable objects like `bool` and `str` this works since you **do not work on the object itself**, but on the resulting array. In you example you used chained indexing, so you modify the inner list.