# Python, class initialization with one value

Tags: python, class, initialization

I have a class which takes two numbers and prints them in a list

```
class Numbers():

    def __init__(self, l, r):

        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def __str__(self):
        print([self.l, self.r])
```

ex:

```
N = Numbers(1, 3) #[1, 3]
```

Now, I need to extend the class so that it can be initialized with only one value

```
N2 = Numbers(2) #[2, 2]
```

Right now I'm a bit clueless on how to proceed, any help is appreciated

Comment: `__str__` is supposed to return a string, not print stuff.

Comment: This might be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382774/initialize-list-with-same-bool-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a default parameter:

```
class Numbers():

    def __init__(self, l, r=None):

        self.l = l
        if r is None:
            self.r = l
        else:
            self.r = r

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.l, self.r])

print(Numbers(1, 2))
# [1, 2]
print(Numbers(3))
# [3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def __init__(self, l, r = None):

    self.l = l
    if r is None:
        self.r = l
    else:
        self.r = r
```

As others already pointed out, you'll need to modify your `__str__` method as well, to be something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.l) + "," + str(self.r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
class Numbers:

    def __init__(self, l, r=None):
        self.l = l
        self.r = r if r else l

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.l, self.r])
```

ex:

```
n1 = Numbers(3, 5)
print(n1)  # [3, 5]
n2 = Numbers(2)
print(n2)  # [2, 2]
```